# Why SSL is false when you open JDBC connection to MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm learning about JDBC and I don't understand something.

I know that the code to open the connection is:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "password");
```

And I have 2 question:

1. What exactly is SSL and why SSL is false?
2. What exactly is the autoReconnect?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't know what properties do, why are you setting them? If you want to know what a property does, check the MySQL Connector/J documentation.

Comment: If I don't set the useSSL property I get this error: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

Comment: The read the documentation, specifically [Connecting Securely Using SSL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html) and [Configuration Properties](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html). Stack Overflow is not a replacement for just consulting the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

1. SSL is a cryptographic protocol which can encrypt all data communicated between the JDBC driver and the server. To use SSL you have to set it up first [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html). The useSSL attribute: default is 'true' when connecting to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ or 5.7.6+, otherwise default is 'false'
2. The MySQL client library can perform an automatic reconnection to the server if it finds that the connection is down when you attempt to send a statement to the server to be executed. If auto-reconnect is enabled, the library tries once to reconnect to the server and send the statement again.

Comment: Thank you Mark! I have MySQL 8.0 and I need to set useSSL=false otherwise I get this error: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.